# Problem booting after fresh install Juno 5.0

Tags: boot

I made a new USB installer using Rufus for the latest version of Elementary OS. The USB drive boots fine and I can use the OS. When I install, the installation works fine. Upon reboot I am stuck on a black screen with a blinking cursor and nothing else. It doesn't matter how long I leave it there. It stays blinking black.

I have installed Linux Mint without any problems.

Comment: I hope our problem is the same, I failed to install Element 5.0 several times, and what I found was when installing by creating other than the system partition, and succeeding when reinstalling the elemntary without partsisi other than the system partition.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was I had two SSDs in the computer and somehow Elementary did not like that. I was booting off the correct one, but somehow it wouldn't work unless I removed the unused SSD. Weird.